# jQuery Rails and tootip not showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Just cant seem to get this tooltip to show any idea where I am going wrong?, the css is working but not the tooltip?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mc_embed_signup').on('ajax:error', function() {  
         var $inputField = $(this).find('input[name="email"]')
        $inputField.addClass('error_field');
        $inputField.tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        offset: [-2, 10],
        effect: "fade",
        opacity: 0.7,
        content: "This email is all ready registered"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the javascript-debugger of your favorite browser. set a breakpoint in the event handler and check if your handler is called at all. Also check the javascript-console for errors.

Comment: Just in case somebody else has the same problem fixed with a second call to `tooltip('show')` and changed `content` to `title:` seems the docs are not that clear as one would assume that the fist call would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody else has the same problem fixed with a second call to tooltip('show') and changed content to title: seems the docs are not that clear as one would assume that the fist call would do the job.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mc_embed_signup').on('ajax:error', function() {  
     var $inputField = $(this).find('input[name="email"]')
    $inputField.addClass('error_field');
    $inputField.tooltip({
    position: "center right",
    offset: [-2, 10],
    effect: "fade",
    opacity: 0.7,
    title: "This email is all ready registered"
    });
    $inputField.tooltip('show');
});
```

});